# Ext. news: can i prioritize a category in list view

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I have news where every news has several categories (1-n).
If i assign my artice detail page in the category tab (Optionen > Einzelansicht für Nachrichten aus dieser Kategorie), in the list view the first available detail page (category detail configuration) is used if have several catageories.

The problem is that i have a category with the names of companies, which should be prioritized.

That means: If the news is tagged with the "company" category, the detail page should be the company page and not the first other category.

anybody an idea how to prioritize a category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is **not** possible. However there are some things you could try:

**1) Change the TCA of the category field**

Instead of using a tree use a traditional list and then you can use the 1st one in the template.

**2) Extend the category model**

Add a checkbox "important" and in the template show only the ones having this set.

**3) Use a special parent category**

All categories below that one are "important" and in the template you check the parent category.

Comment: can i write a new link viewHelper with a changed getDetailPidFromCategories function?

Comment: sure you can ;)